# References not giving expected result

Tags: c++

If I run the below code, it outputs,

```
key: 3, value: 4
key: 32767, value: 1971892984
```

I created this example by mistake, I know that my KV class should not be storing references in its member variables. But I am having trouble explaining this result.

I would have expected that `key_` and `value_` are alias to `i` and `j` on the stack. So they should still be valid when passed to `cout << first` since they haven't been taken off the stack yet. But I can't even guess a reason why the output would be different. Is this an implementation-specific detail that I'm seeing? Or is there something deeper here to understand?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename K, typename V>
class KV {
public:
    KV(): key_(), value_() {}
    KV(K& key, V& value): key_(key), value_(value) {}

    K key() const { return key_; }
    V value() const { return value_; }


private:
    K& key_;
    V& value_;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const KV<T, U> &a) {
    cout << "key: " << a.key() << ", value: " << a.value() << endl;
    strm << "key: " << a.key() << ", value: " << a.value() << endl;
}

template <typename T, class U>
KV<T, U> make_kv(T t, U u) {
    KV<T,U> kv(t, u);
    return kv;
}

int main() {
    int i = 3, j = 4;
    KV<int, int> first = make_kv(i, j);
    cout << first;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have dangling references, and therefore undefined behaviour. The reason is that the references you store in `make_kv` are references to local objects, whose scope is the function itself:

```
template <typename T, class U>
KV<T, U> make_kv(T t, U u) {
    KV<T,U> kv(t, u);
    return kv;
}  // t, u end here!!!
```

You could fix the problem by modifying `make_kv` to take references:

```
template <typename T, class U>
KV<T, U> make_kv(T& t, U& u) {
    KV<T,U> kv(t, u);
    return kv;
}
```

**Note**: You must make sure you understand the copy and assignment semantics of types that hold references. It might be an idea to make the references `const` to limit the scope of unintended behaviour.